# Having two different wall materials, with graffiti on both

Tags: materials, transparency

I am working on an abandoned hospital. I would like to add graffiti here and there on the walls. The graffiti is a PNG with alpha.

I have managed a rudimentary look and feel on a test piece, to be refined a lot soon, but the graffiti seems to make the materials under it transparent too, resulting in this type of image:

[image]

So the question is, what should the node system be to allow three materials on one piece of wall?

Comment: did you try "mix rgb"? https://i.imgur.com/wpm4q8O.png

Comment: That's cool, and I could use that directly, had I only one material on which I need the graffiti to go. However, I have two side by side and the graffiti overlaps them both.

The wall has a noise displacement to mimic stucco on the wall, and the tiles have displacement to mimic tile edges. I think my question is, how to lead out two materials with displacements so that I can add the graffiti at the latest stage.

Comment: check this tutorial --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0ZJyKyAzlA

Comment: Thanks sanbaldo, but I am looking for something really basic, not a product like he's using. The thing can be boiled down to this:

In the upper part of the wall, I need a stucco-like material, wiith displacement.
In the lower part, I need a tile that has an image texture of tiles with displacement.
On top of both, I would love to write graffiti, with a transparent PNG image texture.

What I can't figure out is, do I need more than one UV map for this, or can I run everything on just one UV map.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

The most common way to set this up is to have 2 shaders, one for the wall, and one for the paint.

Then, add a mix shader with both the wall and paint shaders connected. Then, use the alpha output of your image as the factor.

It would look like this:

[image]